# Customize the MFmailcomposer and add dropdown for groups in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, drop-down-menu, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

i had to add the dropdownlist in MFMailcomposer are the before subject field or after subject field.
such that the dropdown contain the groups.
If user select the particular group.it add the specific emails ids.
the list is been managed by the code.

Is it possible.Please help me how to create this drop down in the list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify `MFMailComposeViewController` UI (except using UIAppearance for items, tint color etc) . All Controls will still be there and can't be removed/added/change position.

> You probably have to make your own view controller that mimics
>   `MFMailComposeViewController` and  add your group feature to it.

**In this case however you will have to take care of the sending email part yourself using own backend.**